# How do I create something similar to the HTMLHelper namespace for the business name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, html-helper

I would like to create something that can be called into any view in a website like this

```
@MyBusinessName.TelephoneNumber
@MyBusinessName.Address
etc...
```

In the same way I would call a HtmlHelper

```
@Html.ActionLink()
```

How do I add a namespace like "MyBusinessName" for use in an MVC view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html` in Razor pages is a property of the class that pages inherit from, so of course you can't implement what you want in *the same way* as the standard HTML helper works. **But I can suggest a different solution.**

You may define a static class in your project that will work as your own helper (define there static methods/properties you want to use in views). I'd suggest something like the following:

```cs
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace YourProject.Infrastructure {
  public static class YourBusinessHelper {
    public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(string name) {
      string html = string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" />", name);
      return new MvcHtmlString(html);
    }

    // ...
  }
}
```

[`System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) is a class representing HTML markup that an HTML helper method inserts into the view where it is used. You may create it using a constructor that receives a `string` parameter containing the needed HTML markup — like in my code.

Now you can use this class in your views. You just need to import the containing namespace with this Razor instruction:

```cs
@using YourProject.Infrastructure
```

I'd suggest to put it into the view start file (`_ViewStart.cshtml`) so that it applies to all your views.

The sample helper method above can be used simply:

```cs
@YourBusinessHelper.TextBox("TextBoxName")
```

*UPDATE*: you may also create an extension method for `HtmlHelper`:

```cs
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace YourProject.Infrastructure {
  public static class YourBusinessHelper {
    public static string CompanyPhoneNumber(this HtmlHelper helper) {
      return "+82649256720";
    }

    // ...
  }
}
```

You may use `string` not `MvcHtmlString` in helper methods if they return plain text (no HTML markup).

Use it like a built-in helper method:

```cs
@:Call us: @Html.CompanyPhoneNumber()
```

Comment: Thanks for adding an in-depth response, appreciated.
The htmlhelper extension is where I began, so yes I could do that.
I was just hoping there was a better way by perhaps adding it as a singleton inside the app services, but I can't think of a way to do this.
I could make use of _viewstart, that may the better way for me to resolve this. It's not something that I had thought of so I'll give that a try and see if it 'feels' right.

Comment: I have decided to accept this answer as although it didn't provide me with my expected resolution it was helpful and may be useful to others searching for a similar answer.

Comment: @Ar77 But you wanted to be able to generate HTML markup with something like `@YourBusinessHelper.CompanyTelephone`, right? I told you how to achieve this, right?

Comment: Correct. I thought there would be a better way of doing it than I had already attempted. However I thought your answer deserved to be accepted as you provided a means to achieve it.